# An Object reference is required for the non-static field VideoCapture.QueryFrame()

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, emgucv

So i'm using "**emgu.cv**" to capture an image. I'm new to c# and stuck at the very beginning. Can't figure out how to make it non-static. Have tried a lot of online solutions

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(); 
            Bitmap image = VideoCapture.QueryFrame().Bitmap; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the instance of the class and not the class:

```
Bitmap image = capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap;
```